# what is the likelihood of a levy process?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, stochastic-processes, non-negative-matrix-factorization

While interpreting NMF in Statistical perspective, we assume a Poisson process and to solve for the factors the using EM algorithm, the likelihood of a Poisson process is assumed to be Multinomial, I want to assume a Levy process, What will be the likelihood of a levy process?